# Difference between using "otherwise" and not

Tags: grammar, meaning

Can be ["All things considered, today was an other­wise excellent day in the life of one Addison H. Cooke."](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.ca/books/317792/addison-cooke-and-the-tomb-of-the-khan-by-jonathan-w-stokes/9780147515643/excerpt) changed to "All things not considered, today was an excellent day in the life of one Addison H. Cooke."?  Would this change mess up the original meaning of the author？
"Otherwise" is really difficult to use and understand in some sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [All things considered](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/all-things-considered) is a set phrase. *Otherwise* here means 'apart from one thing that made it a bad day'. The paragraph goes on to say why it was a good day, then the next paragraph explains why it wasn't all good - the protagonist was being told off by the head teacher.